# Парсинг xml из переменной

Tags: c#, xml, синтаксический-анализ

У меня в переменной xml_text записан xml текст вида:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
<settings>
<fist_text>https://vk.com</first_text>
<last_text>http://google.ru</last_text>
<post>12.08.2014</post>
</settings>
<session>
<user_text>Gooogle</user_text>
</session>
</response>
```

Как спарсить session
Пытался вот так (Не выходит):

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(xml_text);
foreach (XmlNode n in xml.SelectNodes("/response/session"))
{
MessageBox.Show(n.Attributes["user_text"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, [XmlDocument.Load(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/875kz807(v=vs.110).aspx) в качестве параметра типа `string` принимает путь до файла, а не строку с `XML`. Для загрузки из строки воспользуйтесь [XmlDocument.LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx).

Во-вторых, у Вас `user_text` - это нода, а не атрибут.

И в-третьих, если Вам нужна одна, вполне конкретная, нода `user_text`, то лучше воспользоваться методом [XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fb63z0tw(v=vs.110).aspx).

Итого получаем:

```
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml_text);
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/response/session/user_text");
        Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText); // Выведет "Gooogle"
```

Comment: Почему всё так трудно ?

Comment: @MadKeks, а что Вам показалось трудным?:) Все довольно просто